# A phrase/idiom for : Slightly bad in something which was almost good

Tags: phrase-requests, idioms

I want to review a place with a good experience except for a little spotty part. Please suggest an idiom for the same.

Comment: I'm confused as to what you're looking for. Could it be 1) A good experience which was slightly tarnished? 2) A mediocre experience that had some good parts? Also, if you could share what idioms you are thinking of that you have rejected, and why.

Comment: @rajah9 The experience was not tarnished and nor mediocre. I meant that experience could have been exceptional had that little bad part not occur, so the experience is still supposed to be good.

Answer (score 2):

Idioms may (or, or at least, carry the risk that they may) make the little spotty part seem more significant than it sounds it was. Two that spring to mind :

- [Fly in the ointment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fly_in_the_ointment)
- [Curate's egg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curate%27s_egg)

If you want to make sure that the problem isn't overemphasised, I'd be inclined to avoid idiom :

> I would have picked a different colour for the table cloths, but the
>   dinner was excellent.

But others might think of some idioms that read as less critical.

Comment: Thanks for those two. Yeah, those still overemphasize the problem and it has to be actually something less critical.